# RSA decrypt message

Tags: c++, c, openssl, cryptography, rsa

My programs fails when I try to decrypt encrypted messages. My code:

```
char   *pri_key[] = "some key"; // ---> some key, that i've got from server

RSA *rsa;
BIO *keybio;
keybio = BIO_new_mem_buf(pri_key, strlen(pri_key));
rsa = PEM_read_bio_RSAPrivateKey(keybio, &rsa, NULL, NULL);

// Decrypt it
// Encoded message is in buff
char *decrypt = new char[BUFF_SIZE];
int decrypt_len = RSA_private_decrypt(BUFF_SIZE, (unsigned char*)buff, (unsigned char*)decrypt,
    rsa, RSA_PKCS1_OAEP_PADDING); // ------> it fails here
```

What is the problem?

Comment: `My programs fails` => How? Where? When?

Comment: Unhandled exception at 0x00921CA4 in Replier.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000008.

In stack call: > Replier.exe!_RSA_private_decrypt()

Comment: @user2123079 Did you try to debug your application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem.

After adding errors checks, I've got error "3132:error:0906D06C:lib(9):func(109):reason(108):.\crypto\pem\pem_lib.c:703:Expe
cting: ANY PRIVATE KEY".

After googling and reading the manuals, I understood that my private key was initialized wrong. I needed to add \n after each line in private key (after each 64th symbol). So the key in char* must be like this:

```
char *pri_key = "-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----\n\
MIIEogIBAAKCAQEAnwOBG9cKqGZhEv3ikSQjrpdEY/qDOB3ZOjoiIT/XJIoPAmXh\n\
i8aAPJ1XgT1enXltvvCmwQDMmcjyAwgKv/215jWN9bcBmRSgTbyJyYCJS4BOs46G\n\
8UKuclXt9JSQGi7ajySdv24qaB+LcchddGIEBtBIWhDx6Je1UxfV9IWk3Ai5zZ5M\n\
e5Ux3mHQz5xUwPncZTN5jBQ3iJTw0Q+NCbHrNZbWKgWEaWJrTGguH1IYVVUcf7qi\n\
PSIPe8jIZeVNVrBkIpX2QYLW2PZxdPPDmFg7dqsTeQRjLwr6grv3arNySMYiU5kQ\n\
VLRyri9FSR5IaqH6tGxjfcNU+7cW3u7gDyD/LwIBAwKCAQBqAlYSj1xwREC3U+xg\n\
wsJ0ZNhCpwIlaTt8JsFrf+TDBrSsQ+uyhFV9vjpWKOm+UPPUoG8rVd2720wCBVx/\n\
/nlEI7P5JKu7YxWJKFvbqwYyVYnNCa9Lgcmhjp6jDbVmyecKGGkqSXGav7JL2uj4\n\
QVgEitrmtfabD843ZTlNrm3oBMQF0rLU888eT/InM424ny0EFjxTARPpEFq0F7jj\n\
95y4FVlHKdAMIhyyUuBe9OEWyl9ALPiIlQNb+5ty1VxF7ZVEJzfwESUzwT9bI+Hj\n\
pYiZAe9vsK/mBYCBJ3X2+qtX56cmCIpk2jnkHFYMnZBrwma108tt3l6Z9kQXBQt2\n\
PNWbAoGBANDyJYvExXkHcxSaElrilWpOG+0cNEGjevgLL54wtQ7e9xGGdJGIo3n4\n\
GmSLrAa9TKrxIMFrKAH/TLEvKyCYnCTpp6lVVRikwUi01rSnm0J0mIZo5VQblgQO\n\
GLrb2yvhFhTV7/WHUFsY7cOQy5EHQKoDYwxkmM31TVQr5A5pbmbVAoGBAMLSvLR3\n\
YgIpdtD6vKVJda6Q9jHzXlgHgXC3vFmDCXFCf7640jrOi8ZI0XkFNr/12OKuVmwF\n\
Gohygq4KeiJVL99Ss3kEFAZmk0m3ZzwbRKwcj6Xolgc6bLWy6AucYEVj1JLEnEs2\n\
HMC/FwClZl7BvbagS6X0XPkfeFyQg0B0V1fzAoGBAItMGQfYg6YE92MRYZHsY5w0\n\
Ep4SzYEXp1AHdRQgeLSUpLZZowuwbPv6vEMHyAR+MxygwIDyGqv/iHYfchW7EsNG\n\
b8Y442XDK4XN5HhvvNb4Za7wmOK9Dq1euyc9PMfrZA3j9U5aNZIQnoJgh7YE1cas\n\
7LLtuzP43jgdQrRGSZnjAoGBAIHh0yL6QVbGTzX8fcOGTnRgpCFM6ZAFAPXP0uZX\n\
W6DW/9R7NtHfB9mF4PtYzyqj5ex0OZ1YvFr3AclcUWw4ypThzPtYDVmZt4Z6RNK8\n\
2HK9tRlFuVom8yPMmrJoQC5CjbctvYd5aIB/ZKsY7unWfnnAMm6i6KYU+uhgV4BN\n\
j4/3AoGACTKWj1cZCKLV7GUnghNooNV5YvOu3xOKGWgoNuey9C6+onFWGXwYbb+N\n\
ArIZraExbCm6OHYfMoR7Zb4rgj5RY9zNoELYQnuTk5MnQJCtzEqEolUuXVAUP8Vn\n\
Xzuh6GkK20/n4PKyIj2ZjN6b534GNPPJYpohhejjdOyetUz4cUI=\n\
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----\n";
```

Thanks everybody for help!

Comment: Please DO NOT publish sensible information... like a private key!

Comment: Ok, I know it. But that was randomly generated key in my test app that I will not use in production code :)